# Display RRT generated by MoveIt

Tags: ros, motion-planning, moveit, rrt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,
is there a way to display the RRT generated by MoveIt for motion planning in something like a picture/map/graphical output? I want to see the differences between the MoveIt planners and therefore it would be helpful to see the planned path, or generated roadmaps. Maybe some of you know a way or tool to do so.

Thanks for your ideas. Im running ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255868/display-rrt-generated-by-moveit/) by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2017-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this could be something that [davetcoleman/ompl_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/ompl_visual_tools) can do.

Also check out [wiki/moveit_visual_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit_visual_tools) and [wiki/rviz_visual_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_visual_tools).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on 2017-03-01**:
Thanks it looks very promising!

**Comment by [Rhemus](https://answers.ros.org/users/29419/rhemus/) on 2017-03-01**:
Do you know if there is a python tutorial/documentation on how to use the tools, especially the first one?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-01**:
I don't think `ompl_visual_tools` can be used from Python. Dave is rather C++ oriented.